# Few questions about proof of theorems in Euclidean geometry

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry

I have two questions regarding proof of theorems in Euclidean geometry.

Many times, a proof of a theorem relies on assumptions about features of a diagram. This is typical of high school books about elementary Euclidean geometry (such as Kiselev's geometry and Harold R. Jacobs - Geometry: Seeing, Doing, Understanding).

Example, a proof that the sum of angles in a triangle is 180° will implicitly assume that points D and B are on the opposite sides of line AC, and points A and E are on the opposite sides of line BC, to apply the theorem that alternate angles are equal.
[image] Line DE and AB are parallel.

I feel that diagrams are essential for making geometry proofs easy to follow. But they cannot be used to justify a conclusion. Every claim (however obvious it may be, for example it is seen from a diagram that two lines intersect) that is made according to a diagram must be proven from the axioms or already proven theorems.

Why are such proof acceptable?

There are many different axiom systems for Euclidean geometry. Do they correspond to the same Euclidean geometry? Why is it so?

Comment: Any proof, diagram or not, can omit details. Many proofs _should_ omit at least some details, otherwise they quickly become unreadable. What level of detail-omitting is considered acceptable is context-dependent.

Comment: *"There are many different axiom systems for Euclidean geometry. Do they correspond to the same Euclidean geometry?"* This (very good) question should be posted separately. You should include specific examples of these "many different axiom systems", though.

Comment: OP if you want to see what Euclidean geometry is like when proving all these technicalities, Euclid's Elements for you.

Comment: @SenZen Euclid's Elements have been known for centuries to be inexact and non-rigorous (even the proof of the first theorem contains implicit assumptions that aren't in the axioms). Try some more modern axiomatic geometry book, like Hartshorne's "Geometry: Euclid and beyond" or Greenberg's "Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries"

Comment: You can read the interesting foreword to Jean Dieudonné's book "Algèbre linéaire et géométrie élémentaire" of which there are translations into other languages. It is a thoughtful essay in which you will find points of view in accordance with what you are wanting to find. (There have been opposing views of notable mathematicians which has raised interesting controversies in this regard).

Comment: A simple way to understand is History :)  Try: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_geometry#The_18th_and_19th_centuries
the mathematical rigor section and then : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms

Comment: The hidden fact is that the standards for "proofs" have varied, and still are to some extent, over the ages.  They all have the same goal, to be "right" and convincing so.  I can citre many examples and it's not finished yet.  For contemporary reflections on this try "Formal Proofs", i.e. COQ and Isabell; in order to get an idea of contemporary attempts.  IMHO they still haven't separated the semantics and syntax completely.   I managed to prove 2=1, thanks to an uncaught/invisible syntax error in Isabell :). But Mathematics is the greatest human-constructed; spanning 1000's of years :)